# Maven pom.xml Spring Boot does not exist

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm new on java world.I have this error "package org.springframework.boot does not exist" on my SpringApplication Runner class.But i added Spring Boot dependency to pom.xml
I do not understand why i got this error.

pom.xml

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

UserDao

```
    @Repository
public class UsersDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void save(Users users){
        entityManager.persist(users);
    }

}
```

UserDTO

```
public class UsersDto {

private Integer id;
private String name;
private String surname;
private String username;
private Boolean isSuperUser;
private String email;
private String password;
private Date created_at;
private Date updated_at;


public UsersDto(){

}

public UsersDto(Users users){
    this.id = users.getId();
    this.name = users.getName();
    this.surname = users.getSurname();
    this.email = users.getEmail();
    this.isSuperUser = users.getSuperUser();
    this.username = users.getUsername();
    this.password = users.getPassword();
}//AND GETTER&SETTER
```

UserResources

```
    @Component
@Path("/users")
public class UsersResources {
    @Autowired
    UsersService usersService;

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response saveCity(UsersDto usersDto){
        Users users;

        try{
            users = usersService.saveUsers(usersDto);

        }catch (Exception e){
            return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }
        return Response.ok(users).build();
    }

}
```

And UserServices

```
    @Service
public class UsersService {

    @Autowired
    private UsersDao usersDao;

    @Transactional
    public Users saveUsers(UsersDto usersDto){

        Users users = new Users();
        users.setName(usersDto.getName());
        users.setEmail(usersDto.getEmail());
        users.setSuperUser(usersDto.getSuperUser());
        users.setSurname(usersDto.getSurname());
        users.setPassword(usersDto.getPassword());
        usersDao.save(users);

        return users;
    }

}
```

User model

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class Users implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="surname")
    private String surname;

    @Column(name="username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name="is_super_user")
    private Boolean isSuperUser;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;


    @Column(name="created_at")
    private Date created_at;

    @Column(name="updated_at")
    private Date updated_at;


    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        created_at = new Date();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    protected void onUpdate() {
        updated_at = new Date();
    }
```

Where is my fault?How can i fix it?And I want to ask similar question.Sometimes we got some errors but i can't find it.So we understand this error's reason is pom.xml dependency conflicts.But no error on maven.We are tired because of incompatible dependency.Has it any solution of prevent dependency conflicts?(like maven dependency validator)

Comment: It could be a Maven dependencies problem, make a maven clean and then update project, to see if now you get the org.springframework.boot.
Ill recomend to create a clean project http://start.spring.io/ and see what dependencies you add that may be on conflict.

Comment: your spring boot version use another version of spring-framework (higher than 4.0.2.RELEASE). remove <version> tag from your pom.

Comment: Create spring boot project using STS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using spring boot a easier way it's to create a Spring Boot project using Spring Initiliazr https://start.spring.io/. You can create from here a maven project that has the Spring Boot or more other dependencies alredeay patched in.

Comment: I was start this website.Then i got 'Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource ' error.Some people told me to use this dependenc and i did.And this problem solved but then i got spring boot error

Comment: You should start with some starter projects from spring initializr and after that you add dependencies to pom.xml if need them. Now your pom.xml is huge and had a lot of dependencies and this cause conflicts. In spring initialzr you can use more starters for you projects, like WEB starter (that packs Spring MVC, Spring Core, etc.) and Data-JPA (that packs spring-jdbc, spring-jpa, etc). Use it

Comment: Thanks dude.I will try it

Comment: If you have more questions after you will create a stable project with some dependencies, I'm here for help

Comment: I prepared my dependencies on this website.I got "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.transaction.SystemException" "BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource" i do not understand i tried all solution on google

Comment: It seems you have the same problem. Put here your actual pom.xml and the class where you define entityManagerFactory bean.

Comment: added more details

Comment: Add this jar in your classpath javax.persistence.jar by adding the specific dependency in pom.xml

Comment: Use EntityManagerFactory instead EntityManager

Comment: i commendet entitymanager line and all depencencies line .But still same error.I think this is not about entitymanager

Comment: Put @Repository annotation on your DAO class.

Comment: Try using this pom.xml and create a new project, building class by class and do a continous testing and report here the errors. I understand that you put another pom.xml but the code it's the same.

Comment: I did it.but same error.I will created new question for this.Thanks for everything

Answer (score 1):

If you use Intellij Idea, you can resolve this problem in such way

1. Right-click on the folder of your project.
2. Choose "Add framework support".
3. Find "Maven" and set the checkbox.
   After that, Intellij starts to download all dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just starting why don't you generate the project using https://start.spring.io/.

You added core Spring dependencies but not a single Spring Boot dependency. You only have a Spring Boot [BOM](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) and [parent](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.0.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.0.0.RELEASE.pom) which only manage dependencies with `<dependencyManagement>`. You can inspect your dependencies by running `mvn dependency:tree`.