# Maven doesn't see Spring dependencies

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I have a problem with Maven refusing to recognize any Spring dependencies. Even though in the POM, everything seems to be correct (nothing highlighted), if I try to compile the app, it throws an error with a message:

```
java: package org.springframework.boot does not exist
```

Also, no annotations work, my IDE simply does not see any dependency it's given and if I try to resolve it by "add dependency"... literally nothing happens. POM itself is fine, because the rest of my team encounter no problems. I have environment variables set with correct paths and options found at Settings -> Build -> Build Tools -> Maven are also set as they should be.

This is my POM (chosen fragments):

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Does it build on plain command line without issues?

Comment: Command "mvn clean install" on command line doesn't say anything about Spring. On command line it gives me another problem... It refuses to recognize one of my company's dependencies which is another headache, because I both have access to the artifactory, <repository> is set correctly within the POM and my settings.xml have both my corporate key and password correct too complete with proper url.

Comment: You need to have a clean build from the command line before looking into your IDE.  What you see is probably caused by something else deeper down.

Comment: I answer a similar question. Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72924187/15524950